# I need help supporting and jacking up my attached, wood front porch

Tags: repair, foundation, joists, porch

I live in Ohio in a home built in 1926.  I do not believe the front porch is that old.  The porch is L shape, wrapping around the house and is 24 X 8' in the front extending another 14' back, with same 8' foot depth.  Attached you will find pictures that may help you answer the question. The porch is supported by 2 X 10's that are 22 inches apart.  The foundation of the porch is red brick that is caving in backwards.

It appears that the entire foundation of the porch is supported by the brick with the joists resting on the corners and a few spots along the porch.  Last year I received an estimate to fix the problem with a price tag of $7000.  No thanks, I want to do this myself.  I am trying to figure out what I need to do to lift and support the existing porch.

The frost line in Ohio is 30".  Also I am planning on removing the existing decking and replace it so I can have total access to the porch which has about 3' of room underneath.

Do I need to dig and pour concrete on each cross joist, can I use a preformed concrete support, can I use a jack to lift into place, etc.?  Attached you will find some pictures that may help.  Thanks everyone!!

[image: Left side of porch with bricks falling backward]
[image: Right side of porch with brick leaning backward]

(Missing images:

- Right side of porch that is secure
- Porch floor
- Porch resting on brick
- Front left of porch showing joists resting on bricks and an apparent repair
- Image of a column of concrete block that does not support anything and apparently an old poured footer

)

Comment: Post the rest of your pictures as links in comments, and someone with more rep will edit them into your question.  Use imgur.com for upload.

Comment: Are you going to re-do the brick as structure? It would be more straightforward to simply support with point loads, although that does mean complete removal of the deck structure. Once you had the deck on posts, you could do decorative brick/wood/anything.

Answer (score 2):

Without awaiting the rest of your pictures, I'll note that if you are removing the decking you're a hop, skip, and a jump from removing the whole porch (or at least the lower frame) which might make it a lot easier to work on. Temporary roof support during porch work is often done with 2x10's angled out into the lawn beyond the porch. Image Search for "porch roof support" if you are not familiar with the concept.

Comment: Was just about to post this.  It seems that you need at least 12 posts - depends on how ledger is secured.  Putting in that many temporary 4x4s and digging and pouring in a 3 foot space seems like a FREAKING NIGHTMARE to me.  Take this thing down in sections if you want to reuse.